# extension of Dictionary where <String, AnyObject>

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift2

I am trying to create a dictionary extension where Dictionary is of the type <String, AnyObject>.

Was looking in many places and trying different approaches, but none of them seemed to work. This was one of them:

```
extension Dictionary where <String, AnyObject>{
    var jsonString:String {
        return ""
    }
}
```

**Another method that didn't actually work for some reason:**

```
extension Dictionary where Key:Hashable, Value:AnyObject {

    var jsonString:String {

        do {
           let stringData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
            if let string = String(data: stringData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
                return string
            }
        }catch _ {

        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

Got: **Argument type 'Dictionary' does not conform to expected type of 'AnyObject'**

Comment: I believe the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475439/swift-define-a-recursive-type-with-a-protocol/32480928#32480928) applies.

Comment: That link has a very ugly solution, surely it should easier then creating two custom protocols

Answer (score 118, accepted):

### >=3.1

From 3.1, we can do concrete extensions, ie:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String {}
```

### <3.1

We can not conform concrete types w/ concrete generics, ie:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String
```

However, because Dictionary conforms to sequence and we can conform protocol types w/ concrete generics, we could do:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == (key: String, value: AnyObject) {
    func doStuff() {...
```

Otherwise, we can constrain our key to a protocol that string conforms to like this:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: AnyObject {
    var jsonString: String {
        return ""
    }
}
```

As per your updated answer.  Json serialization needs an object, Swift Dictionaries are structs.  You need to convert to an `NSDictionary`  You must specify `Key` to conform to `NSObject` to properly convert to an `NSDictionary`.

> Small note: Dictionaries already type constrain `Key` to be `Hashable`, so your original constraint wasn't adding anything.

```
extension Dictionary where Key: NSObject, Value:AnyObject {

    var jsonString:String {

        do {
            let stringData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self as NSDictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
            if let string = String(data: stringData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
                return string
            }
        }catch _ {

        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

Note, that the dictionaries must conform to this type to access the extension.

```
let dict = ["k" : "v"]
```

Will become type `[String : String]`, so you must be explicit in declaring:

```
let dict: [NSObject : AnyObject] = ["k" : "v"]
```

Comment: This is what I get with your code: `error: type 'Key' constrained to non-protocol type 'String'`

Comment: @MartinR - Thanks for pointing it out, I swapped it for `StringLiteralConvertible`.  I think this possibly satisfies the intent.

Comment: Yeah basically I should specify protocols not types, found list of protocols that really helped me https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/#protocols

Comment: @AndriusSteponavičius - See above

Comment: Your dictionary needs to conform to the type constraints: `let dict: [NSObject : AnyObject] = ["k" : "v"]`.  The other option is to attempt a cast within like `if let convertible = self as? [NSObject : AnyObject]` then use that to make NSDictionary `convertible as NSDictionary`

Comment: @AndriusSteponavičius - Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?  I believe it answers your original question, as well as your additional appended questions.

Comment: I believe its almost answered but if it takes to declare dictionary in an intuitive way and use extension in slightly unnatural way I will try to find a nicer solution, if I wont be able to I will accept it as answer

Comment: @BenLeggiero what about `Key: AnyHashable`?

Comment: @Logan `<unknown>:0: error: type 'Key' constrained to non-protocol type 'AnyHashable'`

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3 Approach**

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Value: AnyObject
```

As StringLiteralConvertible is now deprecated and replaced by ExpressibleByStringLiteral

Answer (score 8):

**Update for Swift 3**
Here is my example using `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` for `Key` and `Any` for `Value`.

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: Any {
    var jsonString: String? {
        if let dict = (self as AnyObject) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            do {
                let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: UInt.allZeros))
                if let string = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                    return string
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

and then I use it like this:

```
let dict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [...]
let jsonString = dict.jsonString
```

You can convert self to AnyObject or NSObject, both works, then you do unwrap as Dictionary or any other specific type.

Comment: in swift 3: StringLiteralConvertible  is now: ExpressibleByStringLiteral

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the answer provided by @Logan, for those looking to add custom properties to the string-subscripted `Dictionary`, that is possible as well (was looking to do this when I came across this SO question):

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible {

    var somePropertyThatIsAColor:UIColor? {
        get {
            return self["someKey"] as? UIColor
        }
        set {
            // Have to cast as optional Value
            self["someKey"] = (newValue as? Value)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Anyone using `[String:Any]` instead of `Dictionary` can use below extension

```swift
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Any {

    mutating func append(anotherDict:[String:Any]) {
        for (key, value) in anotherDict {
            self.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So, `Dictionary` is:

```
public struct Dictionary<Key : Hashable, Value> : CollectionType, DictionaryLiteralConvertible {..}
```

How about a protocol extension? :D

```
extension CollectionType where Self: DictionaryLiteralConvertible, Self.Key == String, Self.Value == AnyObject, Generator.Element == (Self.Key, Self.Value) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to make any of the offered solutions work in Swift 3, but by taking advantage of bridging between Dictionary and NSDictionary I could make this work:

```
extension NSDictionary {

    var jsonString:String {

        do {
            let stringData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: .prettyPrinted)
            if let string = String(data: stringData, encoding: .utf8) {
                return string
            }
        }catch _ {

        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems swift 3 doesn't support Dictionary extensions out of the box. If you add this: ``protocol AnyDict{}
extension Dictionary:AnyDict{}`` and then do ``extension AnyDict{}`` You can at least drop NSDictionary out of the equation. Casting via ``as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>`` may apply inside extension methods