# How to create Dictionary extension

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have this code to get a `Double` amount from a `[String: Any]` and format a string like this

```
if let amount = details["amount"] as? Double
{
    self.amountLbl.text = String(format: "%.2f", amount)
}
```

Im trying to create an extension for this

Expected

```
//self.amountLbl.text = details.getInAmountFormat(str: "amount")
```

My attempt

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringProtocol {
    func getInAmountFormat(str: String) -> String? {
        if let value = self[str] as? Double {//Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<Key, Value>' with an index of type 'String'
            return String(format: "%.2f", value)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost done, just make right constraint on the `Key` type:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String {
    func getInAmountFormat(str: String) -> String? {
        if let value = self[str] as? Double {
            return String(format: "%.2f", value)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Also, here is an useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32610322/2463616).